# Label properties not switching to selected layer for labelling

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro my labelling properties is "stuck" on one layer i.e. not switching to allow other layers, fields and classes to be manipulated (the field do not change based on the selected layers attributes either). The attached screenshot even shows that this happens on projects where the layer "stuck" in layer properties isn't even within the project I have open. Is this a bug in the labelling?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried closing ArcGIS Pro, an re-opening it to see if the problem persists?  If so, then have you tried rebooting in between closing and re-opening ArcGIS Pro? What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?

Comment: I tried few restarts of eh program yesterday before posting. Overnight its been rebooted, still no luck today. Version is 2.6.1